# Making a custom UIView subview that fills its superview

Tags: ios, swift, layout

So I wrote my own custom view with its own initializer. However, when my main view loads my custom view gets depicted in a wrong way. It takes bounds as 600x600 rectangle, while the superview is 375x607. I did try to put auto constraint, seems not to work. I tried to do it programmatically in the subview initialization, but whenever I try to initialize it's bounds property to its superview bounds I get nil in superview.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

func setup() {
    initPathLayer()
    initHandleView()
    initHandlePanGestureRecognizer()

    layoutPathLayer()
    layoutHandleViews()
}
```

I tried everything there is on the internet to make subview fill its superview, but I think that subview gets initialized before superview? Is that possible ? In the ViewController a have my custom view declared as an Outlet connection. I'm sure that the problem should be super easy and it's me who doesn't know the way Swift initializes the view.

Any ideas ?

Thank You.

Comment: Try showing which constraints you added as that should work. Otherwise there's the layoutSubviews method you can override to explicitly set the frame

Comment: The thing is that the subview doesn't see its superview, until it's initialized. I'll make screen shot of constraints

Comment: Just looking at your code you should only call layout methods inside of layoutSubviews

Comment: Thank you! That was just it. As I said, it was a very small problem and the cause of it was my inexperience.

Comment: Haha no worries, but you should definitely be able to represent this in constraints so I'm worried that that's not working

Comment: I posted an in depth solution to your question, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Firstly, a Views init method is not the best place to perform a layout. The view could be resized at a later point which is typically always the case if the view is loaded from a Xib or you are creating it in a View Controllers `viewDidLoad` function.

That being said you have several approaches:

### 1. Use Auto Layout

#### Interface Builder

This can be done either in Interface Builder or programmatically. In Interface Builder you simply use the 'Pin' option and select all the sides of the view

[image: Pin Constraints]

When this is done you should be able to see your constraints in the Size inspector looking as follows:

[image: Size Inspector]

#### Programmatically

Alternatively you can always add your constraints programmatically in your initializer:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    super.init(frame: frame)
    let viewsDict = ["view": view]
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    addSubview(view)
}

convenience required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init(frame: .zero)
}
```

### 2. Manual Layout

#### Resizing Masks

For this you can either use resizing masks or you can control the frame in layoutSubviews. Resizing masks tell the system how the view should be sized relative to the superview:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    super.init(frame: frame)
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
}
```

#### Layout Subviews

Lastly, you can override layoutSubviews and go from there:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    view.frame = bounds
}
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote more! In case it helps others, I had a sub view constrained to its superview. It looked fine on devices running iOS10. In devices using iOS 9, the subview took up the whole screen covering the superview. By adding the lines  view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
and view.frame = bounds, my problem was fixed.