# Why the 20px gap at the top of my UIViewController?

Tags: ios, layout, uiviewcontroller, xamarin

### The Problem

Consider the following controller hierarchy:

- `UINavigationController`

  - `UIViewController`

    - `UITableViewController`

The presence of the `UIViewController` is affecting layout. Without it, the `UITableViewController` takes up the entire bounds of the `UINavigationController`:

[image]

However, if I add a vanilla `UIViewController` between the `UINavigationController` and `UITableViewController`, a 20px gap appears between the top of the `UIViewController` and the top of the `UITableViewController`:

[image]

Even if I reduce my code down to the simplest possible thing, I still observe this behavior. Consider this app delegate code:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    var tableView = new UITableViewController();
    var intermediateView = new UIViewController();
    var navigation = new UINavigationController(intermediateView);

    navigation.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    intermediateView.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
    tableView.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;

    intermediateView.AddChildViewController(tableView);
    intermediateView.View.AddSubview(tableView.View);
    tableView.DidMoveToParentViewController(intermediateView);

    window.RootViewController  = navigation;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

    return true;
}
```

The above *still* shows a 20px gap between the top of the `UIView` and the top of the `UITableView`.

### My Understanding of the Problem

I understand that *something* is erroneously allocating space for a status bar. Using Reveal I can see that the `Frame` of the `UITableViewController` has a `Y` value of `20`.

### Things I've Tried

#### Unsuccessful

- Set `WantsFullScreenLayout` to `true` on the `UIViewController`, `UITableViewController`, and both
- Playing with `EdgesForExtendedLayout` and `ExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` for both the `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController`
- Played with `AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` on the `UIViewController`
- Played with `PreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` in the `UITableView`
- Tried overriding `PrefersStatusBarHidden` and returning `true` in both the `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController`

#### Successful

Overriding `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` in my `UITableViewController` thusly:

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
    this.View.Frame = this.View.Superview.Bounds;
}
```

### Things I want to know

- is there a clean(er) way of achieving my goal?
- what is actually responsible for adding the 20px gap? The `UIViewController`? The `UITableViewController`?
- what are the best practices for ensuring my view controllers remain usable in different contexts? Presumably overriding `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` couples my view controller to expectations as to where it will be displayed in the visual tree. If it were to be hosted higher up the controller stack, things would not look right. Is there a way to avoid this coupling and thus increase reusability?

Comment: Make sure that you don't have a translucent navigation bar

Comment: Also make sure you didn't accidentally set the tableview inset

Comment: @KingBabar: even the simplest possible repro demonstrates this problem. See the code in my updated question. I'm not setting *anything* - I'm just using vanilla view controllers.

Comment: the translucent is a check mark in the story board of the nav bar. If your not using storyboard then the default for nav bar is to be translucent. And you need to change it to NO

Comment: @KingBabar: like I said, I'm using code - not storyboards. See my question.

Comment: the default for translucent is YES you need to change it in code to NO

Comment: Also try to remove setting the bg color code because it triggers the view did load prematurely

Comment: Now the nav bar has moved over the status bar and the gap is still there, but now it's black. I'm confused: are you saying you're running the same code as in my question and are getting a different result?

Comment: What script is that you are using. I thought it was Swift, but on closer inspection it's not.

Comment: @James Webster: it's C# (using Xamarin)

Comment: Ah! I use c# but I was blind to in while in "iOS mode" I replicated it using swift, so I can rule out the problem being with xamarin. I haven't found a solution / cause yet though

Comment: All that was needed is to set your views frame explicitly http://stackoverflow.com/a/30614342/1652402

Comment: Updated my post in Xamarin, let me know if you need further assistance:)

Comment: UIViewController leaves 20px for status bar. There are 2 option either use UITableView and add it as subview in view controller or add UITableViewController as child. Make table header view size is in both case. As table header view also is of 22px

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is not a bug at all but merely a side effect of your misuse of adding views into a hierarchy.

When you add the tableView into a view you need to tell UIKit how you want that tableView to size relative to its parent. You have two options: [Auto-Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) or Autoresizing Masks. Without describing how you want your view to layout `UIKit` simply pops it onto the hierarchy and the default implementation will lay your view under the top layout guide (which just happens to be the height of the status bar). Something as simple as this would do the trick:

```
tableVC.View.Frame = rootVC.View.Bounds
tableVC.View.Autoresizingmask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
tableVC.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true// always nice to explicitly use auto layout
```

This behavior is not actually exclusive to `UITableViewController` but also to `UICollectionViewController`. I believe their default viewLoading implementation insets the view under the status bar. If we make our childController a simple `UIViewController` subclass none of this behaviour is exhibited. Don't see this as a bug though, if you explicitly declare how you want their respective views to be laid out you won't have this issue. Naturally, this is the primary function of a container controller.

Heres what your appDelegate should look like:

### Xamarin

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    var tableVC = new UITableViewController();
    var rootVC = new UIViewController();
    var navigationVC = new UINavigationController(intermediateView);

    navigationVC.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    rootVC.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
    tableVC.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;

    rootVC.AddChildViewController(tableVC);
    rootVC.View.AddSubview(tableVC.View);


    //YOU NEED TO CONFIGURE THE VIEWS FRAME
    //If you comment this out you will see the green view under the status bar
    tableVC.View.Frame = rootVC.View.Bounds
    tableVC.View.Autoresizingmask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    tableVC.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    tableVC.DidMoveToParentViewController(rootVC);

    window.RootViewController  = navigationVC;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

    return true;
}
```

### Swift

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navigationControlller: UINavigationController!

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let rootVC = UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    let tableVC = UITableViewController(style: .Plain)
    let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
    navVC.navigationBarHidden = true

    navVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    rootVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    rootVC.view.addSubview(tableVC.view)

    //YOU NEED TO CONFIGURE THE VIEWS FRAME
    //If you comment this out you will see the green view under the status bar
    tableVC.view.frame = rootVC.view.bounds
    tableVC.view.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight
    tableVC.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)

    rootVC.addChildViewController(tableVC)
    tableVC.didMoveToParentViewController(rootVC)

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = navVC
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

**Note** I wrote a [post recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29766851/1652402) describing the ways you can configure a view to fill its superview

Comment: Awesome answer, and it worked a treat. For some reason I thought the default behavior was for a subview to fill its parent view. Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem seems to relate to some kind of fundamental issues with `UITableViewController` being directly added as a child controller of another.

Looking around this is not a new issue: [iOS 7: UITableView shows under status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900428/ios-7-uitableview-shows-under-status-bar)

Relative to that article, I took your code and tried the following options (once I realized it was in C# 8^)):

1. Instead of using a `UITableViewController`, add a `UIViewController`
   and then add a `UITableView` as a child of the `UIViewController`.
   If you do this then there is no 20pt issue. This highlights that the
   problem is with the `UITableViewController` class.

   This approach is a relatively clean workaround and only a couple of
   extra steps on what you have already.

   I did try adding constraints in your original code to force the
   UITableViewController frame to the top, but could not get this to
   work. Again this could be down to the table controller overriding
   things itself.
2. If you build your demo using storyboards, everything works. This I
   believe is down to the fact that IB itself uses a container view to
   embed the new view controller. So if you use storyboard, the way
   apple does it is to add a view which you can set the frame of using
   constraints and it then embeds the `UITableViewController` inside
   that view via an embed Segue.

   Hence as per 1), using a view in the middle seems to solve the issue
   and again it seems that having control over the middle views `frame`
   is key.

   I notice in your only viable workaround, that changing the frame was
   the answer. However post iOS7, changing the frame does not seem to
   be recommended due to the issues it can have clashing with
   constraints which also want to manipulate the frame.
3. Trying other options like `edgesForExtendedLayout` all seemed to
   fail. These seem to be hints for container view controllers and
   UITableViewController is ignoring them.

IMHO I think option 1) seems the safest approach as you have total control over the layout and are not fighting the system with frame overrides which may cause you issues later. Option 2) only really works if you use storyboards. You could try doing the same thing manually yourself, but who knows what goes on in an embed Segue.

**EDIT**

It would seem that there was a missing step as highlighted by Arkadiusz Holko in his answer and setting the frame explicitly for the table view does fix the issue.

Comment: I don't think the OP is using constraints at all thats why he wasn't getting warnings. Its just bad practice to have a view control its own frame. All that was needed was setting the tableViews frame and resizing masks... http://stackoverflow.com/a/30614342/1652402

Comment: @sschunara Not sure if you commented on the wrong answer? Your options are what I put in this answer. However, the real fix (or correct code really) was found to be to set the frame of the child controller.

Comment: @Rory McKinnel yes sorry I need to comment it on the question.  I deleted from here.

Answer (score 6):

You missed one step when adding a child view controller – setting up its view's frame.

See the second step:

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
  [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
  content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
  [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
  [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: This is a better solution, but try contextualise your answer rather than pasting sample code:)

Comment: I pasted this as a reference of how Apple advises setting up child view controllers. The question doesn't use Objective-C or Swift, so I wasn't sure if my code would compile.

Comment: Only issue with this is that it doesn't mention any use of auto layout or resizing masks. Should probably bring that up with Apple:)

Answer (score 4):

20 pixel is taken by the status bar. If you are using an xib file or storyboard with auto layout you can set the top constraint to **top layout guide** so that the 20 pixel difference is handled

Comment: I'm creating the controllers in code. See my updated question for simplest possible repro. No custom code at all - just creating the controllers and establishing their relationships. Still creates a 20px gap.

Answer (score 2):

**Is there a clean(er) way of achieving my goal?**

Just change the frame.

```
tableView.View.Frame = intermediateView.View.Bounds;
tableView.View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

**what is actually responsible for adding the 20px gap? The UIViewController? The UITableViewController?**

You can log `UIViewController.view.frame` after you new a `UIViewController`.
You can see `UITableViewController.view.frame` always have a 20px gap. Why? I think Apple just initialize `UITableViewController.view` with screen size with a 20px top padding.

**what are the best practices for ensuring my view controllers remain usable in different contexts? ...**

If you want to add a `UIViewController.view` to another `UIViewController.view`.The best way is use story board and use `Container View`.

If you don't want or can't use story board. I suggest just subclass `UIView`. `addChildViewController` sometimes have annoying problems with life circle and layout.

Comment: I wouldn't say the "best way" is to use a storyboard. It can easily be done programmatically, especially since the OP doesn't appear to be using a storyboard at all