# Cannot find superview while adding constrains programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Referring this question [Making a custom UIView subview that fills its superview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763818/making-a-custom-uiview-subview-that-fills-its-superview) while trying to add constraints programmatically.

I am using the code below to add two constraints programmticly; however, I get an error states that "Unable to parse constraint format" because the related view doesn't have a superview.

```
private func setupDownView(view: UIView) {
    let downView = try? DownView(frame: view.bounds, markdownString: "")
    downView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let viewsDict = ["view": downView!]
    downView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[view]-0-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: viewsDict)[0])
    downView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[view]-0-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: viewsDict)[0])
    view.addSubview(downView!);
}
```

[image]

Does the `view` auto become the superview once it has been added to its subview?

I have tried to add the view before setting up the constrains by `addSubview` before `addConstraint` and I get the error "The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint".

[image]

`setupDownView` is called in the following two places,

```
@IBOutlet weak var cardTags: UIView! {didSet { setupDownView(view: cardTags)}}
@IBOutlet weak var cardContent: UIView! {
    didSet {
        setupDownView(view: cardContent)
        let tap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(QuizViewController.tapDownHandler)
        )
        tap.minimumPressDuration = 0
        cardContent.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an answer at below as a reference for those have the similar issue ?

Comment: I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constraints need to be added **after** view is in the hierarchy. So `addSubview` call must be **before** `addConstraint` calls.

Also ensure that `addConstraint` is called on it's superview, not `downView`, and that **all** constraints returned from `constraintsWithVisualFormat:` are added, not only the first one.

```
private func setupDownView(view: UIView) {
    let downView = try? DownView(frame: view.bounds, markdownString: "")
    downView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(downView!);

    let viewsDict = ["view": downView!]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[view]-0-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: viewsDict))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[view]-0-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: viewsDict))

    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code but my `downView`s disappeared. :(

Comment: No error at all, it just does not show on the view any more.

Comment: Does superview have any constraints in Storyboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135491/discussion-between-li-xinyang-and-legoless).

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 8, you don't have to figure would which view to add constraints to, just activate them. For individual constraints, just set `.isActive` to `true`.  To activate an entire array of constraints, use the `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()` convenience method.

For your code, instead of doing:

```
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[view]-0-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: viewsDict))
```

You'd use:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[view]-0-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: viewsDict))
```

This works because the constraints already know which view or views they refer to, and *Cocoa* or *Cocoa Touch* can figure out the appropriate view in the view hierarchy to add the constraints to, which can be tricky depending on how the views are related (eg. siblings, parent/child, other).

The same caveats apply here.  You need to make sure the views are in the view hierarchy **before** activating the constraints, or you will get errors.  So, do `.addSubview` before activating the constraints.